# What is the Drupal 7 jQuery syntax for $(window).load?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

This works in Drupal 7:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function myfunction($) {
});
```

But what is the syntax for $(window).load?

This seems not to work:

```
jQuery(window).load(function myfunction($) {
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to add a margin to my footer, but after all other elements are rendered. Otherwise my page structure messes up.

Comment: you should really use css for that, not javascript…

Comment: Yeah, but this isn't a normal margin, but a conditional margin. It adjusts according to the window height, and more factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
jQuery(window).bind('load', function() {
  // Function code
});
```

Edit to add example of Drupal jQuery noConflict code:

```
;(function($) {
  $(window).bind('load', function() {
    // Function code
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Update: Also changed erroneous `myFunction` to the proper `function` keyword.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Note: I believe the '$' in the function variable space is necessary for Drupal.

Comment: Not quite, `$` is an alias to the function `jQuery` so you only need to pass the `$` variable to your function if you want to use `$.function` instead of `jQuery.function`. This is the format to use for that: (function($){ // code using $ })(jQuery);